# How to reconstruct POST data from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Below is a screenshot from Chrome devel tools, where I have clicked on a Search button on a website. I'd like to be able to perform the same search from a script.

When I click on View Source in the Form Data tab I get:

`MENUGRID=&TIETOJABUTTON=&LOPETABUTTON=&TOSITEGRID=&HENKILOCOMBO=123456&TILACOMBO=&TOSITETYYPPICOMBO=&ALKUPVMEDIT=&LOPPUPVMEDIT=&TIEDOKSICHECK_CHECKBOX=off&LASKUNUMEROEDIT=&ETSIBUTTON=&ETSINUMEROLLABUTTON=&IW_Action=ETSIBUTTON&IW_ActionParam=&IW_FormName=ArkistoForm_1&IW_FormClass=TArkistoForm&IW_SessionID_=132amw21txnotj18td6840sblhd1&IW_width=&IW_height=&IW_TrackID_=6`

I have tried adding various combinations of RequestURL and I always get session expired errors.

**Question**

How can I figure out what to prepend the above POST data with? Is it e.g. the RequestURL with an added `?`

Here is a copy of the HTML/JS source where the Search (called "Søg") button is. https://pastebin.com/8HQMwD8W

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is capable of preparing a cURL command with all of request parameters (including cookies which are needed for authorization, as said by AlexProutorov). Just click on your request name (`bwtem`?) with right mouse button and choose `Copy as cURL` from the `Copy` menu.

Answer (score 0):

Server requires your request to be authorized so you should also supply your request with the same Cookies header as you captured using Chrome dev tools. This is where session data is stored.